# Balance Stays Zero

Tags: substrate

`await api.query.system.account('5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY')` returns `{ nonce: '0', consumers: '0', providers: '0', data: { free: '0', reserved: '0', miscFrozen: '0', feeFrozen: '0' } }`  and  `await api.query.system.account('5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY')`
returns `{ free: '0', reserved: '0', miscFrozen: '0', feeFrozen: '0' }` with the following genesis.json

```
    "palletBalances": {
      "balances": [
        [
          "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
          1152921504606846976
        ],
```

using the substrate node template `3.0.0`
I've tried to use the balances pallet instead of the system pallet to store the balances but still

Comment: The behavior you are seeing is exactly what you would expect when changing the storage. You should be querying `api.query.balances.account` to find the balance of the user since you have moved the storage there instead.

Comment: I know what you mean and i already tried that
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/8288